# touch any place outside popup menu(self draw) to hide the uiview

Tags: iphone

I have created myself popup menu(draw an uiview and list some items).
But I hope when touch any place outside the uiview, the popup menu will disappear.

I try to use

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

    //UITouch* touch = [touches anyObject];


}


- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{ 
}
```

to catch the touch event, but it looks like sometime the function above are not triggered.

Welcome any comment

Thanks

interdev

Comment: check if userinteraction is enabled for all view, and if you want to detect touches event just for some specific view,just register that view to UITouch* instead of UITouch *touch = [touches anyobject];

Comment: yes, every userinteraction is enabled. I hope it can catch any touch outside the uiview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you implement in the touchesCanceled:withEvent: ? 
Sometimes the touch flow will be touchesBegan -> (touchesMoved) -> touchesCanceled, no touchesEnded happaned.

Answer (score 1):

I have done this in the past by creating a custom UIView and then overriding the pointInside method of the UIView class.  That is the method that will fire every time a UIView gets a touch notification.  When that happens you can then find out whether or not the touch was inside or outside of your views bounds.

For example your custom UIView could look like this:

**CustomTouchUIView.h**

```
#import 

@protocol CustomTouchUIViewDelegate

- (void) uiViewTouched:(BOOL)wasInside;

@end

@interface CustomTouchUIView : UIView 

// Properties
@property (nonatomic, assign) id delegate;

@end
```

**CustomTouchUIView.m**

```
#import "TOTouchUIView.h"

@implementation CustomTouchUIView

#pragma mark - Synthesize
@synthesize delegate;

#pragma mark - Touches
- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if( point.x > 0 && point.x < self.frame.size.width && point.y > 0 && point.y < self.frame.size.height )
    {
        [delegate uiViewTouched:YES ];
        return YES;
    }

    [delegate uiViewTouched:NO ];
    return NO;
}
@end
```

I have a downloadable example / tutorial online [here](http://kellenstyler.com/index.php/2011/09/20/adding-touchoutside-functionality-to-a-uiview-in-ios/)

Comment: You can use `CGRectContainsPoint` instead of that `if`.